# Passing std::vector::data to function expecting type** (double pointer)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, pass-by-pointer

As the title describes, I am trying to pass the pointer to the data of a `std::vector` into a function expecting a double pointer. Take as an example the code below. I have an int pointer `d` which is passed to `myfunc1` as `&d` (still not sure if call it the pointer's reference or what), where the function changes its reference to the beginning of an int array filled with `1,2,3,4`. However, if I have a `std::vector` of ints and try to pass `&(vec.data())` to `myfunc1` the compiler throws the error `lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`. I have already tried something like `(int *)&(vec.data())` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18727928/5969548), but it does not work.

Just for reference, I know I can do something like `myfunc2` where I directly pass the vector as reference and the job is done. But I want to know if it's possible to use `myfunc1` with the std::vector's pointer.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

void myfunc1(int** ptr)
{
    int* values = new int[4];
    // Fill all the with data
    for(auto& i:{0,1,2,3})
    {
        values[i] = i+1;
    }

    *ptr = values;
}

void myfunc2(vector<int> &vec)
{
    int* values = new int[4];
    // Fill all the with data
    for(auto& i:{0,1,2,3})
    {
        values[i] = i+1;
    }

    vec.assign(values,values+4);
    delete values;
}

int main()
{
    // Create int pointer
    int* d;

    // This works. Reference of d pointing to the array
    myfunc1(&d);

    // Print values
    for(auto& i:{0,1,2,3})
    {
        cout << d[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Creates the vector
    vector<int> vec;

    // This works. Data pointer of std::vector pointing to the array
    myfunc2(vec);

    // Print values
    for (const auto &element : vec) cout << element << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // This does not work
    vector<int> vec2;
    vec2.resize(4);

    myfunc1(&(vec2.data()));

    // Print values
    for (const auto &element : vec2) cout << element << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** What my actual code does is to read some binary files from disk, and load parts of the buffer into the vector. I was having troubles getting the modified vector out of a read function, and this is what I came up with that allowed me to solve it.

Comment: You can't re-assign the underlying storage of a `std::vector`.

Comment: A better way to print the elements of a `vector`: `for (const auto &element : vec2) cout << element << " ";`. You do not need to create an array of indexes and iterate over it to access the vector elements.

Comment: A function like `myfunc1` that does manual memory management is fundamentally incompatible with `std::vector`. Iterators exist to abstract this entire problem away. If a function wants to set elements in a range to something, it can do that by assigning to output iterators given to it. Can you tell us what this whole setup is supposed to achieve?

Comment: @MaxLanghof My actual code is to read a binary file and part of the buffer is passed to a vector. I was having troubles getting the modified vector out of the function that reads the file, and something like `myfunc2` is what has been working for me.

Answer (score 2):

When you write:
`myfunc1(&(vec2.data()));`

You are getting the address of a rvalue. The pointed `int*` is so a temporary that is destroyed right after the call.

This is why you get this error.

But, as ***@molbdnilo*** said, in your `myfunc1()` function, you are reassigning the pointer (without caring to destroy previously allocated memory by the way).
But the `std::vector` already manages its data memory on its own. You cannot and you must not put your hands on it.

---

> What my actual code does is to read some binary files from disk, and load parts of the buffer into the vector.

A solution could be to construct your `std::vector` by passing the iterator to the beginning and the iterator to the end of the desired part to extract in the constructor's parameters.

For example:

```
int * buffer = readAll("path/to/my/file"); // Let's assume the readAll() function exists for this example

// If you want to extract from element 5 to element 9 of the buffer
std::vector<int> vec(buffer+5, buffer+9);
```

If the `std::vector` already exists, you can use the `assign()` member function as you already did in `myfunc2()`:

```
vec.assign(buffer+5, buffer+9);
```

Of course in both cases, you have to ensure that you are not trying to access an out of bounds element when accessing the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot take the address of `data()`, since it is only a temporary copy of the pointer, so writing to a pointer to it makes not that much sense. And that is good that way. You DO NOT want to pass `data()` to this function since it would overwrite the pointer with a new array and that would break the vector. You can remove one `*` from the function and only assign to it and not allocate the memory there. This will work, but make sure to allocate the memory in the caller (with `resize`, just `reserve` will result un undefined behavior, since `data()` is only a pointer to the beginning of the valid range `[data(), data() + size())`. The range `[data(), data() + capacity ())` is not necessary valid.