# Passing 2d std::vector to a function expecting pointer to pointer of type

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

Consider:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

void print_1d(int* array, int size) {
    for (size_t i = 0, szi = size; i < szi; ++i)
        printf("%d\t", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void print_2d(int** array, int nrows, int ncols) {
    for (size_t i = 0, szi = nrows; i < szi; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0, szj = ncols; j < szj; ++j) {
            printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    //1d array vs 1d vector
    int* one_d_heap_array = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        one_d_heap_array[i] = i;
    std::vector<int> one_d_vector = { 3, 4 };
    print_1d(one_d_heap_array, 2);
    print_1d(one_d_vector.data(), 2);
    //2d array vs 2d vector
    int** two_d_heap_array = new int* [2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        two_d_heap_array[i] = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            two_d_heap_array[i][j] = 10 * i + j;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> two_d_vector =    {   {1001, 1002, 1003},
                                                        {3001, 3002, 3003}
                                                    };
    print_2d(two_d_heap_array, 2, 3);
    // print_2d(two_d_vector.data(), 2, 3); // <-- line gives compiler error
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        delete[] two_d_heap_array[i];
    delete[] two_d_heap_array;
}
```

To summarize, to a function that expects an `int*`, one can pass `std::vector<int>::data()`.

Is there an equivalent way a 2d vector can be passed to a function expecting an `int**`?

The commented out line in the code:

`print_2d(two_d_vector.data(), 2, 3);`

gives error:

```
argument of type "std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int **"C/C++(167)
```

Thinking along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740094/stdvector-vec-data-or-vec0) thread, I tried the following. They do not work either:

`print_2d(&two_d_vector[0], 2, 3);`

`print_2d(two_d_vector[0], 2, 3);`

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135673/passing-stdvectordata-to-function-expecting-type-double-pointer) thread from earlier, but there, the user is attempting to pass a 1d vector to a function expecting an int**, which is different from the content of the current question.

Comment: `int **` expects a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. A `vector<int>` is a container that holds a pointer to an `int` and a bunch of book keeping. A `vector<vector<int>>` is a container that holds a pointer to a `vector<int>` and book-keeping. While the `int**` and `vector<vector<int>>` do the same thing, they do it different and incompatible ways. and can't be inter-mixed. Make a function that takes `vector<vector<int>>` preferably as a `const` (because you aren't changing any of the date) reference.

Comment: @user4581301 agreed with the bookkeeping stuff. I don't expect int* and std::vector<int> to behave the same. However, in the case of std::vector<int>, the ::data() member function provides all the interfaces that an int* requires.

Comment: Tactical note: You may find a [simple matrix class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301) a little easier to use than `vector<vector<int>>` and `int**` and it's often a lot faster because it keeps all of the data in one big block instead of having pointers to pointers to different blocks of memory ruining the effectiveness of caching.

Comment: Right, but the `data()` of the outer `vector` is a pointer to `vector<int>` and you need a pointer to `int`. There is no easy way to turn the `vector<int>`s into plain old `int*`s.

Comment: In this specific case you could cover both cases using a template, since both `int**` and `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` allow you to retrieve a reference to an int using `[]` twice, assuming all inner vectors have sufficient size. `template<class T> print_2d(T print_2d, size_t nrows, size_t ncols) { ... }`

Comment: @user4581301 Ah. I see now. Essentially, outer dimension's data() is a pointer to *bookkeeping stuff* that is not the actual data. In case of int**, the outer pointer directly points to an integer. Gotcha. Looks like I would have to use the matrix class or else the template method as suggested by fabian

Comment: @user4581301 Would it be a reasonable assumption that data in an std::vector<std::vector<int>> (not the bookkeeping stuff) is **not** stored contiguously in memory?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct assumption. Typically a `vector` is a pointer to an array of data, a pointer to the first empty spot in the data (size of the `vector` is the second pointer - the first), and a pointer to the end of the array (so you can easily tell when the vector's full). No data is actually inside the `vector`. In a `vector` of `vector` the outer `vector` has a pointer to an array of inner `vector`s, each of which points to its own array of data. No guarantee that all of these arrays are anywhere near one another in memory.